# How do you display Taskbar notifications?

Tags: c#, .net, taskbar

How would one go about displaying taskbar notifications?

I want to write an app that periodically displays a flash card esque notification, the intention is to see if a 5 second or so distraction every hour can help with language learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the application you describe, I probably wouldn't use a notification icon or taskbar icon. You'll likely need a larger window displayed, with larger font.

I'd open a frameless window (possibly faded or scrolled into view) that sits in the lower-left of the desktop. (Although of course remember that not everyone has the taskbar at the bottom of the screen).

As an example, look at what Outlook or many RSS readers do to notify of new messages - this feature is commonly called a "toast" pop-up.

Comment: How do you get a frameless window?

Answer (score 7):

In .NET you can use the [Notification Icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972170.aspx) to place a notification in the system tray.

Comment: You can combine this with a custom application context to not require a form at all, and just use the balloon text.  It works very well.