# C# : Notifying window upon some event

Tags: c#, winforms

i wants to display a windows upon some event like (i received data on socket). I wants to display the windows as animated, appearing from system tray and go to top. Like mostly antivirus notifies like this.

how can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either winforms or WPF for your purpose.  [Click here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_TaskbarNotifier.aspx) for WPF example.

After seeing the comments, I have added couple of links for winforms also

[TaskbarNotifier, a skinnable MSN Messenger-like popup in C# and now in VB.NET too By John O'Byrne](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx)

[NotifyWindow: A different MSN Messenger style notification window By Robert Misiak](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/RobMisNotifyWindow.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there any helpful link for winforms

Comment: this one is exactly according to my requirement. but i need this in WinForms

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about writing an application that can minimize to the taskbar and display notifications then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217871/how-do-you-display-taskbar-notifications) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476086/how-do-i-show-a-taskbar-notification-in-my-c-application) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey check this project at codeproject [TaskbarNotifier, a skinnable MSN Messenger-like popup in C# and now in VB.NET too](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx). You can customize based on your need for a new look and feel.